# struggling with understanding the @objc method swift 4

Tags: swift, timer

```
    func updateTimer() {
            counter = counter - 1
        if (counter > 0) {
            countDown.text = String(counter)
        } else if (counter == 0) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "testComplete", sender: self)
        }
    }

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(("updateTimer")) , userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

I'm receiving the error "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer"

Answer (score 1):

If the class does not inherit from `NSObject` so you have to add the @objc attribute to the action method.

Just like:

```
@objc func updateTimer() {
        counter = counter - 1
    if (counter > 0) {
        countDown.text = String(counter)
    } else if (counter == 0) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "testComplete", sender: self)
    }
}

Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer()) , userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Also use `#selector(updateTimer())` instead of `#selector(("updateTimer")).`

Comment: You should also mention the need to fix the use of `#selector`.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani when I use your revised code, I get the error "objc can only be used with members of classes, objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes"

Answer (score 1):

Some changes to your code:

```
@objc func updateTimer() {
       ...
    }

#selector(updateTimer) // swift 4
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this  `#selector(("updateTimer"))`

use below code

```
 #selector(self.updateTimer())
```

**or**

```
#selector(updateTimer)
```

and your code will be

```
func updateTimer() {
        counter = counter - 1
    if (counter > 0) {
        countDown.text = String(counter)
    } else if (counter == 0) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "testComplete", sender: self)
    }
}

Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer) , userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
//Change ClassName to the name of the class
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ClassName.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```